# How to check if a division is possible before the code runs in python?

Tags: python, division

I'm trying to check if a certain division statement could be executed (there are no strings, no division by zero, etc...) before the code runs and gives me an error. I can't use exceptions and have to use if statements. I know how to check for each condition, but I need one statement that checks generally if the division is possible or not. 
This is my code:

```
a = input("Enter first list:")
b = input("Enter second list:")
def my_divide(a,b):
    if  (a statement to check if [(ai/bi) for ai, bi in zip(a, b)] would work):
        return [(ai/bi) for ai, bi in zip(a, b)]
    else:
        return [], "Something is wrong. Can't perform division"

print my_divide(a,b)
```

Comment: Checking for division by zero is easy, and checking for numeric values is only a little more difficult. But checking for floating-point overflow is very difficult without exception handling. Do you need to check for overflow?

Comment: Do you mean a division in general, or an integer division? Because, with strings and zeroes aside, every number is divisible by every other number (except 0 and INFs). The result can be fractional though.

Comment: No worry about overflow. And it has to be integer division. Basically both a and b need to be lists, contain only int elements and no zeros in b for the division to work. Like I said checking individually is easy, but I need a general statement for all.

Comment: Can you call a function in your if statement  that uses exceptions?

Comment: No I can't. The point of the exercise is to work around exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to try & fail, of course. You never know what will be non-doable or non-divisible and for what reasons.

However, let's assume your input data are clean, no strings, no zeroes, just the numbers. Then you can just `print('YES')`, because every number is divisible by every other number (except 0 and +INF/-INF) with the fractional result.

So the questions is strange in that case. But since the question is asked, I assume you want an integer division.

For an integer division, and with the integers at hand, you have to check if `a % b` (remainder of division) is zero, which means that `a` is *divisible* by `b`:

```
if all(ai % bi == 0 for ai, bi in zip(a, b)):
    pass
```

Or, the same:

```
if all(not ai % bi for ai, bi in zip(a, b)):
    pass
```

---

You can go further, and assume that a & b contain not just integers, but floats. Here, the stdlib's [`fractions`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/fractions.html) module comes to the rescue:

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction

>>> f = Fraction(10, 2)
>>> f.numerator
5
>>> f.denominator
1

>>> f = Fraction(10, 3)
>>> f.numerator
10
>>> f.denominator
3

>>> f = Fraction(2.5)
>>> f.numerator
5
>>> f.denominator
2
```

This class "normalizes" the fractions to the least integer numerator & denominator possible. For any value, including a float, to be divisible, the denominator must be `1`.

Here, 2.5 is divisible by 0.5 with no remainder:

```
>>> f = Fraction(2.5) / Fraction(0.5)
>>> f.numerator
5
>>> f.denominator
1
```

To check:

```
if all((Fraction(ai) / Fraction(bi)).denominator == 1 for ai, bi in zip(a, b)):
    pass
```

---

PS: However, beware of the precision problems in the incoming numbers. For example, `0.01` will be not a fraction of `1/100` as you would expect, but something completely terrible:

```
>>> Fraction(0.01)
Fraction(5764607523034235, 576460752303423488)
```

In that case, you can *force* the fraction to have a limited denomiator, possibly losing some precision in the value. For example, limiting to 6 digits after the comma (i.e., `1/1000000`):

```
>>> Fraction(0.01).limit_denominator(1000000)
Fraction(1, 100)
```

Comment: This one is exactly what I need! Thank you so much!

Comment: @RBair I've extended the answer for the float values in a & b.

Comment: Thanks! Would it be possible to do something about strings? when I put a string into the list it's giving me an "unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'str'" error instead of passing.

Comment: Covert them to `int(ai) % int(bi)`. For the `Fraction` class, it does this already.

Comment: I tried and it gave me this: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'i'

Comment: Because `'i'` is not an integer. As you said, "there are no strings, no division by zero".

Comment: the string wasn't 'i'. I don't know where that came from. My question was, how do I make it pass if it is a string not an integer?

Comment: You can take a look at `str.isdigit()` & `str.isnumeric()` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) — they might be of use to quickly check the content of the string.

Answer (score 1):

This will catch non-numeric values and zero denominators.

```
if (isinstance(ai, numbers.Number) and isinstance(bi, numbers.Number) and bi != 0)
```

Of course, the `numbers` module must be imported before this. However, catching floating-point overflow is very difficult in an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this with a try function. Something like:

```
def my_divide(a, b):
    quotient = []
    for ai, bi in zip(a, b):
        try:
            quotient.append(ai/bi)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            quotient.append('Something is wrong. Cannot perform division')
    return quotient

print my_divide(a, b)
```